# One controller with few views or three more structured - ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I need to redesign one module and there is one controller with some action methods:

**FriendsController**
with action methods:

```
FriendsList()
FriendsRequests()
FriendSearch()
```

I think that this can be designed better. And I think to change it to something like this:

```
FriendsController - Index/Show/Edit
FriendsRequests - Index
FriendSearch - Index
```

Is the second option better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subjective question but yes, I'd say 2nd option is better.  As you already noted for 'FriendsController', there are additional methods needing to be created.  I'd suggest this will end up happening to FriendsRequests as well (eg Confirm, Create, List/index, Show etc).

You could go all out and separate them into an Area if you were so inclined.